# Dates between dates in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm keeping track of "duty" days for a company.

I've got a google sheets form that people input their day with. Each entry generates a row and I'm looking to flag sets of rows when they work 5/6/7 days in a row.

5 in a row is "getting close"
6 is "maxed out"
7 is a violation

So we'll say it looks a bit like this...

```
[Date]   [Start]  [End]  [Activity]    
1/1/2018    9am    5pm   office stuff    
2/1/2018    9am    5pm   more office stuff    
3/1/2018    9am    5pm   still doing office stuff
```

When it gets to 5 days in a row, I'll change the background colour of that row to yellow... etc.

The date comparitors seem geared towards comparing two columns though, not consecutive columns. Google won't allow me to put functions into form submissions (for obvious reasons) but I can run things from a header cell comparing submitted cells... just not consecutive ones (as opposed to columns which are pretty trivial in comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a custom formula

```
=sumproduct(countif(A:A,row(indirect(A2&":"&A2-4)))>0)=5
```

It says that there must be at least one instance of every day from the current date down to four days before it (5 days inclusive).

So if current date is 17/2/18

the person must have worked on 13/2/18, 14/2/18, 15/2/18 and 16/2/18 for the rule to fire.

Then you need to repeat the rule for 6 and 7 days

```
=sumproduct(countif(A:A,row(indirect(A2&":"&A2-5)))>0)=6
```

and

```
=sumproduct(countif(A:A,row(indirect(A2&":"&A2-6)))>0)=7
```

The last rule must be applied first

[image]

**Note**

These will also work in Excel if logical result of > comparison is coerced to a number

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&A2-4)))>0))=5
```

etc.

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&A2-4))))
```

is possibly the shortest way of doing it in Excel but would have to be wrapped as an array formula in Google Sheets.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I'll give it a shot when I get home.

Comment: Thanks Tom... just getting my head around this... it seems that the functions live on each row?

I'm adding rows via a google sheets form, so unfortunately I can't have functions on the rows themselves and have to instead evaluate them externally.

At the moment, I'm having to run things through an external script to do so.

Comment: It took a while to realize that you're talking about putting conditional formatting on the whole column... I didn't know you could do that... very handy.

I've got a script running on the column to calculate the days at the moment, but I might swap over to your style as it looks a lot more efficient.

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can put conditional formatting on as much of the column as you depending on the range you select when setting up the rules.

Comment: Yeah man.
And in this way, it sorta acts like a for-loop. Quite handy.
My challenge is that I'm dealing with Web-Form submitted rows, so I can't manually select anything... but selecting the whole row includes all future rows, so it works.